# Accidentally formatted an OS X Journaled disk to one exFAT partition

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, external-disk, exfat

I was stupidly doing things too fast and accidentally formatted my WD 1TB drive instead of a thumb drive.  The drive was originally OS X Extended journaled encrypted and the operation attempted to format it to exFAT.  Both would have had only one main partition.

I tried to follow the answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230379/recover-deleted-encrypted-os-x-extended-volume)

but had no success.  A couple things were different for me though, so I thought someone out there might be able to help.

1. My format to exFAT did not complete successfully as I had files and other items from the WD drive open at the time I clicked format.
2. My partition table after doing a `sudo get -r show /dev/disk2` was the way klanomath said an HFS+ table should look before doing anything.
3. When performing a `diskutil cs list` the only CoreStorage device is my internal disk.

This sort of leads me to suspect that something has gotten messed up with the CoreStorage data, but I'm no expert.  Any help is greatly appreciated as there are some photos and audio recordings on there that I would really like to get back.

Comment: if it's not a core storage device it won't show up with `diskutil cs list`. You'll need `diskutil list` instead

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I think the issue is that it used to be a core storage encrypted volume and the format wiped out that information somehow.  I was able to duplicate the same issue by trying to erase a thumb drive that was core storage while it was mounted.  This led to the partition table staying the same but the lvg being unrecognized