# Recover accidentally reformatted encrypted drive

Tags: hard-drive, partition, catalina, encryption, data-recovery

My external USB-HDD formatted in HFS+ (journaled) and encrypted was reformatted yesterday by accident to HFS+ (journaled) - but no encryption.

The standard data rescue tools fail to find any of the files on the formerly encrypted partition and do not allow to ask for a password.

As a next step I only found [Recover deleted Encrypted OS X Extended volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230379/recover-deleted-encrypted-os-x-extended-volume) - but could not yet try the steps as one more recovery tools is scanning the data now.

What can I do to handle this special case regarding encryption?

Comment: Chances are very, very low if you formatted the disk to gpt/JHFS+ (+EFI-partition), higher if formatted to MBR/FAT32|ExFAT (no EFI-partition). File-based data recovery is   completely useless on locked (unmounted) encrypted volumes.

Comment: Is there any chance to mount it?

Comment: Thanks. I have the latest version (believe 15.x) and will send you the details any minute.

Comment: Unfortunately, it was not successful trying t orecover using the linked methodology. The volume header holding the secret key and meta information was already overwritten. @klanomath thank you so much for anyway trying to help me.