# Recover formatted Encrypted MacOS Extended volume to HFS+ (HFS+ Encrypted to HFS+)

Tags: macos, partition, recovery, encryption, hfs+

I've just accidentally formatted my 1TB HFS+ Encrypted partition (also known as Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)) to HFS+ (Mac OS Extended (Journaled)) and lost all my data!
Is it possible to bring all data back as it was (by changing the partition table or like [This thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230379/recover-deleted-encrypted-os-x-extended-volume)) or even scan file by file?
(I know the password. The whole disk is in 3 partition consist of NTFS and APFS file format if it matters)

Comment: It's gone.  How old is your backup?

Comment: I haven't any backup at all.

Comment: The thread in your link is for when you have formatted with a different partition style (GUID to MBR).  Doesn't apply in your case.  Backup (if you had one) would be the solution to your circumstances.